# IBM BPM: Is it possible to hide a column of a table dynamically based on user choice?

Tags: uitableview, ibm-bpm

Since I'm new to this technology (Coach UI) I wanted to know an information, is it possible to delete a column based on the user's choice?
That is, I have a modal that contains the column fields and if I choose to hide a column it hides it dynamically.
Thank you in advance for the reply, I have been on this problem for 2 days :(

Answer (score 0):

Configurations of Controls in BPM can be either provided with values or bound to a variable.
Binding configuration item to a variable will give you the ability to change it dynamically, by changing the value of that variable.
For your request, you can click on the purple icon next to Columns (image bellow) to switch to binding mode, then select a varible of type TableColumn (This BO is available in the UI Toolkit itself, open the BO to check the documentation).

[image: Columns specs bound to variable]